# При копировании текста из одного unicode документа в другой летит кодировка (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, bom

Мне надо открыть ряд .txt доков, сделать нехитрые манипуляции со строкой и записать результат работы в другие доки (в юникоде). Исходные доки разной кодировки (Windows-1251 и UCS-2 LE BOM).

Вот основной кусок кода:

```
inFile = open(file, mode='r')  
outFileEng = open(fileName, mode='w', encoding='utf-16-le')  
outFileEng.write('\ufeff')  
for line in inFile:
    outFile.write(line + "\n")
```

В результате файлы, которые были в кодировке Windows-1251, записываются без нареканий, а вот то, что было в ucs-2 le bom получается вот таким
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Была жалкая попытка сделать

```
line = inline.strip('\ufeff')
```

но это не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

`open()` не пытается угадать кодировку, а просто использует `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` по умолчанию (вероятно, cp1251 на русской Винде).

Вы можете в вашем случае самостоятельно кодировку определять:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import codecs
import locale

with open(input_filename, 'rb') as file:
    data = file.read()
if data.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE):
    character_encoding = 'utf-16'
else: # ANSI code page
    character_encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding(False)

lines = data.decode(character_encoding).splitlines()
print(*lines, sep='\n')
with open(output_filename, 'w', encoding='utf-16') as file:
    file.writelines(line+'\n' for line in lines)
```

Для выходного файла используется utf-16, а не utf-16-le, чтобы BOM записать.

Comment: О, спасибо! Я попробую это решение) вечная проблема с кодировками станет немного понятнее.